# PowerShell, Variables Declared Inside a loop, can be accessed outside?

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to PowerShell scripting and mostly work with C#. I understand that there are three types of scopes - global, local, and script level. I know that variables declared inside a function cannot be accessed outside, unless the scope modifiers are used.

However, I am having confusion when it comes to variables that are declared inside a loop. To understand the issue, please have a look at this example:

```
foreach ($i in 1..3) {
    $innerVariable = $i
}

# Accessing $innerVariable outside the loop
Write-Host "Value of innerVariable: $innerVariable"
```

I assumed that it would give me **$null output** or some kind of error message. However, in this case, it gives me **3**, which is the correct output. That means variables declared inside loops can be accessed outside. I have noticed the same behaviour in Do-While loop:

```
$retryCount = 0
do {
    $response = New-InvokeSomeHttpRequest -ErrorVariable reqError
    $retryCount++
} while(($reqError.Count -gt 0) -and ($retryCount -lt 3))
```

With the above, I can access **$reqError** outside the loop, when the request has failed 3 times.

**So I have the following questions:**

1. Am I missing something, or is this the default behaviour?
2. Is there any advice on this, i.e., best practices?
3. If this is the default behaviour, would it be better to declare the variable outside the loop, e.g., **$myVar = $null**, and then overwrite it inside the loop? If you want to use that variable outside.

Thanks

Comment: 1 and 3 are correct, and assumption 3 is the best practice for point 2

Comment: You can use $global:variableName I think it can work too.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the rules and guidelines of this place *before* posting.  This post has a number of issues, including asking many questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question and soliciting opinions about "best practices" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: @possum, who's afraid of best practices?

Comment: If you read the link and the follow up question I posted they fall under the general "asking for opinions" blanket.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based

Answer (score 2):

*Special thanks to **mklement0** for shedding light on these two key insights: "**functions and script files are just named script blocks**" and "**Module functions ... run in the root scope of their module.**" Additionally, I'd like to thank **sirtao** for introducing the term "**memory sheet**" in reference to scope. While **not** official terminology, it changed the way I was thinking. Scope, in PowerShell, isn't solely about location; it also dictates which block of memory is currently manipulated - a crucial understanding that I think many people, including myself, are failing to grasp.*

### Understanding Scope Transitions and Spawning

There appear to be two primary categories of scope changes, but considering no change in scope as a type would make a total of three types:

**1. Continuation in the Same Scope.**

- All control structures (loops: `foreach`, `while`, `for`, `switch`; conditionals: `if`/`else`) and dot-sourced script blocks (`.`), including functions (`. functionName`) and scripts (`. .\scriptName.ps1`), operate within the current scope, with identical access to variables as all other code operating in the current scope.

**2. Transitioning to a Newly Created Child Scope.**

- All called (`&`) script blocks, this includes cmdlets and functions (`& functionName` and `functionName`) and external scripts (`& .\scriptName.ps1` and `.\scriptName.ps1`), create new child scopes, allowing read access to the caller's variables (Parent's variables) and modification of the contents of caller's reference type variables (e.g., hash tables, collections) and the individual elements in caller's arrays (You can not add or remove elements, only modify the contents of existing elements.). Including read access to the caller's/parent's parent's scope, all ancestor scopes, and the root/global scope.

  - This includes module functions, but since they run in their module's scope, there are differences.

    - From experiments, they appear to run in a child of the root scope of their module.

      - Read only access to root variables in their module by default.
      - Read only access to variables in caller's scope.

        - Dot sourcing (`. moduleFunctionName`) does not change this.
      - Read/write access to root variables in their module through "script:" scope modifier
      - Read/write access to root variable in the callers script through "global:" scope modifier.

**3. Transitioning to, or Spawning, an Isolated Scope.**

- However, remote sessions, jobs, and `ForEach-Object -Parallel` execute in an isolated new scope, which lacks direct access to variables in the caller's scope.

#### A different way of looking at it

For anyone who read this far, and are still having difficultly understanding how scopes work, maybe you will find these analogies helpful:
**Whiteboards = Scopes and related memory blocks**
**Rooms = Sections of code**
**Paper = Arguments passed to, or values returned from, functions, script blocks, scripts, etc...**
**Employees = threads/jobs**

1. **Transitioning to a Newly Created Child Scope:**

   - Imagine you're in a room with a whiteboard on the wall and pieces of paper in hand. You work on the whiteboard and possibly write on the paper. Then, you move to a new room, taking with you a photo of the whiteboard and the paper. Repeat this process in subsequent rooms, taking with you the paper and all photos of previous whiteboards. However, upon finishing, and returning to each previous room, you only return with the paper and those photos of rooms taken prior to entering the current room. You eventually return to the original room, where you have only the original whiteboard and the paper you've had all along.
2. **Transitioning to, or Spawning, an Isolated Scope:**

   - Imagine you're in a room with a whiteboard on the wall and pieces of paper in hand. You work on the whiteboard and possibly write on the paper. Then, either you move to another room, or your employees move to other rooms, carrying only the paper, and working on the paper and the whiteboards in those new rooms. Repeat this process in subsequent rooms, with each person carrying only the paper as they go.  Upon finishing, and returning to each previous room, each person returns only with the paper. Eventually, everyone returns to the original room, where there is only the original whiteboard and the paper in hand.
3. **Continuation in the Same Scope:**

   - Imagine you're in a room with a portable whiteboard on wheels and a pieces of paper in hand. You work on the whiteboard, and possibly write on the paper, and then move to a new room, taking the whiteboard and paper with you. This process continues as you move to subsequent rooms, with all the work retained on the whiteboard and paper throughout each move. Whether or not you return to the original room, you always have the whiteboard and paper with you, working on both as you move from room to room.

Comment: Good overview. The array case is just one example of the reference-type case: you can modify the instance itself, assuming it supports that, and arrays happen to support modifying existing elements (only). You mention script blocks: ultimately, functions and script files are just _named_ script blocks, so the underlying unit of execution to which the behaviors apply is a script block, whether explicitly created as such or implicitly via a function or a script file.

Comment: It isn't just other runspaces (whether on another thread or out-of-process) that don't see the caller's scope, but also functions in (different) _modules_. Module functions only see the _global_ scope (and run in the root scope of their module).

Comment: That's very useful information. For your first point, control structures operate within current scope and can access and modify variables in that scope, but what happens if one of these control structures e.g., foreach, defines a variable inside it? Does that variable becomes part of the current scope and can be accessed outside that foreach?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370133/can-i-answer-if-im-not-sure

Comment: @MGDev Yes. They "write" their values and names on the same "memory sheet"(scope). Unless you were talking about `Foreach-Object -Parallel`: in that case the `-Parallel` parameters cause it generate a new Scope for each parallel event and thus the contents aren't available in the "original" scope

Comment: @MGDev, any modification to variables, including creating new variables, remains a part of that scope.  I haven't seen a scope referred to as a "memory sheet" as sirtao mentioned, but it makes a very effective mental image.  You write something new to the sheet and it remains there until you erase it. But if you create a new sheet, and copy info from the old sheet to the new sheet, all modifications to the new sheet have no effect on the old sheet.  But, if you use the info on the new sheet to find where something is, such as the locations of an array, you can modify the contents of the array.

Comment: @mklement0, finally got around to updating this.  Thank you again!  Probably needs more work and proof reading, but done for now.

Comment: My pleasure, @Darin; thanks for the shout-out. I actually misspoke when I said that module functions run in the root scope of their module: They only do so _when dot-sourced_, surprisingly even by an _outside caller_ (and when invoked directly / with `&`, they run in a _child_ scope of their module's root scope). All non-module code and each module gets its own stack of scopes (which in SO answers I have called _scope domains_, but which the official docs confusingly call _session states_), and they share only the global scope. Any function runs _in its scope domain of origin_.

Comment: P.S., @Darin: You may find this post interesting: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10797#issuecomment-1981533087, which aims to provide a top-down PowerShell "ontology".